# jQuery Ad gallery thumbnails: need to link to pages not images. How to edit .js file

Tags: jquery, gallery

I'm using the jQuery ad gallery in a site, only I want to have the thumbnails link to urls specified in the a custom field. Everything is working fine except that the jQuery is not letting the user click on the thumbnail and go to the corresponding page. I probably should have used a different plug in but I'm pretty deep into this.

Is there a way to make it so that the thumbnails will link to the url specified in the href attribute?

Here's a link to the site:
http://cucumbermarketing.com/~customco/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Sorry for posting so soon!

Answer (score 1):

You can jump into the jquery.ad-gallery.js and find this block:

```
link.click(
  function() {
   context.showImage(i);
   context.slideshow.stop();
   return false;
}
)
```

then go ahead and comment the

```
//return false;
```

I would suggest to get rid of this function but just commenting this line of code will do the trick!

Good luck!